# How do you say "like after 2 hours" in German?

Tags: grammar, adverb

> So nach 2 Stunden standen meine Frau und meine Kinder auf, um das Frühstück zuzubereiten.

Like after 2 hours my wife and my kids woke up to make breakfast.

Based on my book "***so***" has many meanings in German one of those is "***such***". Is "so" correct in that context?

Comment: Off-topic: What does "like after 2 hours" look like in correct English?

Comment: What's so important about *so* meaning *such*?

Comment: I agree with @teylyn, it's not clear what you're asking. The "like" can be omitted in your example in English and it adds nothing, unless you clarify your exact meaning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In colloquial German we can use *so* for expressing inaccuracy. The usage is similar to the English *like*.

Examples:

> So nach 2 Stunden ist die Prüfung fertig.
>   Eine neue Dichtung kostet so 2 bis 3 Euro.
>   Meine Eltern wohnen so 100 km weit weg.

In all cases the adverb (e.g. *circa, ungefähr, etwa, ...*) was omitted in colloquial speech.

Answer (score 2):

Ich würde sagen "Nach etwa (oder circa) 2 Stunden..." oder "Etwa / circa 2 Stunden später / danach..."

Comment: This does not answer the question. We were asked whether "so" can be used similar to the English colloquial *"like"*.